# Align model to camera view

Tags: camera

In camera view, how do I perfectly align my model? For example, I want a side view of my space ship (or front/back)
I can move the camera around but that's not exact!

Thank you

Comment: do you want to align the camera with the object or align the object with the camera?

Comment: Use the Numpad buttons to get the proper orthographic view. 1 = front, 3 = side, 7 = top, 9 = invert whatever position you're in (ie top becomes bottom)

Answer (score 3):

If it's aligning the view to an object or element you're after, explore the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> combinations.

They will align the view down the selected element's Y, X, and Z axes, respectively.

- If the element is an object, that's down the object's axes, towards its origin.
- If a face, Z is down its normal, X and Y look straight across its plane.
- If it's an edge, Y looks straight down it, and X, Z, align the edge
  parallel to the screen,
- and finally, if a vertex, Z looks straight down the vertex normal,
  and the others bring the vertex normal parallel to the screen.

Adding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the key combinations gives you the reverse angles of the above.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> will align the active camera to whichever view you are in.